# Error in onpreparedlistener () for videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to have a progress bar before the video loads in videoview. But I get the following errors. I have also added all the necessary imports.
[image]
[image]

I am using AIDE IN ANDROID

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 ProgressBar progressBar = null;

VideoView videoView = null;

String videoUrl = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";

Context context = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle iclic) {
    super.onCreate(iclic);

    context = null;

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);

    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    videoView.start();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1,
                        int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

        }
    });

}

}
```

Didn't understand what the problem is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, work perfect

replace  `new OnPreparedListener()`  with `new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()`   and `new OnVideoSizeChangedListener()` with `new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener()`

Comment: Thanks bro for the help. Great relief